# linux loadable kernel prints messages on console

Tags: linux-kernel

If I have this then it will leave a system log message. 
I would like to print messages on console.
How do I do this? I am running the program on Ubuntu with 3.2.x kernel..
Thanks in advance.

```
    printk(KERN_INFO "[%s] : [%d]\n", string, count);
```

Answer (score 0):

KERN_INFO might go to the console, it depends on how the system is configured.  The action of putting it a log is being handled by a daemon.  For example, on a system using rsyslog you can put

kern.* /dev/console

in /etc/rsyslog.conf, restart the daemon, and then all kernel messages will go to the console.

Answer (score 0):

use `KERN_ALERT` instead of `KERN_INFO`. KERN_ALERT is the highest priority over KERN_INFO.

```
printk(KERN_ALERT "[%s] : [%d]\n", string, count);
```

Refer http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-4-sect-2 for more info.